# Can't set title for terminal window when launched from Gnome menu launcher

Tags: redhat, gnome, gnome-terminal, freedesktop.org

I added a new Gnome menu option to launch a custom script application. I am using Redhat 6, Gnome 2. This is all working but when it launches in a new terminal window I cannot get the title to display anything other than the default 'Terminal'.

Here's how I have it configured; I have added the following files to get it working:

- /usr/shared/applications/app.desktop ( configures launching of my application )
- /usr/shared/desktop-directories/app.directory (specify a directory from menu for my app)
- /etc/xdg/menu/application-merged/app.menu ( adds menu option to main Applications pull down menu)

The app.desktop file specifies the location of the script I want to run and I have set the 'Terminal' option to 'True' which launches it in a new terminal window. I have tried adding the following to during startup of the script but it doesn't change the title.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0; APP TITLE\007"'
```

Setting the 'PROMPT_COMMAND' from a separate, interactive terminal DOES work though. Not sure why it doesn't work when launching from the gnome application launcher.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't really set the terminal window title I have tried everything even modifying files but to no avail. The method which your using is meant to be put in the .bashrc in the home folder but doesn't seem to work.

```
gnome-terminal --title="example"
```

The command above which I have tried doesn't work either

Comment: Thanks. This command works for me. It generates a new terminal though. I use --tab to create additional tabs "gnome-terminal --tab --title="example"